# HTTP error while scraping images using urllib in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I have a list of urls and I am using following code to scrape images from websites, using urllib in python3.

```
i=0
all_image_links=[]
r=requests.get(urllink)
data=r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
name=soup.find('title')
name=name.text
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image_link=link.get('src')
    final_link=urllink+image_link
    all_image_links.append(final_link)
for each in all_image_links:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(each,name+str(i))
    i=i+1
```

I am encountered with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "j1.py", line 91, in <module>
    import_personal_images(each)
  File "j1.py", line 63, in import_personal_images
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(each,name+str(i))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 188, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I found few solutions on the web and changed code to :

```
1):

all_image_links=[]
i=0
req = Request(urllink, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
r=webpage.decode('utf-8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image_link=link.get('src')
    all_image_links.append(urllink+image_link)
for each in all_image_links:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(each,str(i))
    i=i+1

2):

all_image_links=[]
i=0
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(urllink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image_link=link.get('src')
    print(image_link)
    all_image_links.append(urllink+image_link)
for each in all_image_links:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(each,str(i))
    i=i+1
```

and i am still getting the same error. Can someone explain where my code is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

[**HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) - the server understood the request, but will not fulfill it for some reason unrelated to authorization.

The server is actively denying you access to this file. Either you have exceeded a rate-limit, or you are not logged in, and attempting to access a privileged resource.

No amount of code, unless that of the authorization / authentication type, will resolve this error.